# Google Drive and Local Directories in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, symbolic-link, google-drive

I want to create a symbolic link between local directories and my Google drive. In other words, I don't want to synchronize it by hand. If there is a change in the directory, it should synchronize it autonomously. Also, I don't want to put all my directories into the drive directory since it dumps all the file system mentality in OS X.

I saw some methods for Windows, but I couldn't find any solution for Mac. How do you deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the Google Drive Application? Works quite fine for me, in both ways actually. (Syncing online changes to my local folder and the different way around.)

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive

Comment: I am using Google Drive already. But I want to use it with some tricks like auto-controlled google drive. I mean, lets say there are lots of directories in your desktop which you work with as much as possible and you worked a lot with different directories and files during day. At the end of the day, you don't remember (or don't want to deal with syncing one by one) which the files and directories you had changed. So there should be a way which google drive takes responsibilities to do that. Like background process, drive can synch your files "automatically" if you changed it.